# How do you print a 4 x6 photo keeping full frame from a cell phone image?

Tags: printing

I want to print the exact image taken from my cell phone.

I know the aspect ratio is different on a cell phone then it is on a standard digital camera.

Is there an app that will print my cell phone image full frame on an 8 x 10 photo paper without cutting off my cell phone image?

Comment: Just to be clear, you don't want to crop any of your image, and you know the aspect ratios are different between the phone and 8x10? Do you understand that the only thing left is to distort the image so it will fit without cropping? What do you mean when you say you "want to print the exact image"?

Comment: Do you want to print a 4"x6" image inside an 8"x10" sheet of paper? Are you considering trimming away the borders by hand afterwards? Are you asking about ratios or actual inches?

Comment: I do not want to crop my cell phone image. I want to keep it as is.  I want to be able to print the cellphone image onto either a 4 x 6 or an 8 x 10,if possible.

Comment: You already said that - it's the rest of the information we still need.

Comment: All I am asking is it possible to print a cell phone image onto a 4 x 6 or 8 x 10 sheet of photo paper without anything being cut off from my original cellphone photo? I hope this clarifys my question. Thank you.

Comment: It doesn't really. If your aspect ratio is different from that of the paper, then you will either have to crop some image to fill the paper, or you will end up with white borders to trim off manually… or you could stretch the image so it's longer in one direction than it should be, which will look bad. Square peg, round hole.

Comment: Thank you. So,I guess from your answer that there is no way to print my cellphone image without some compromise of my original, .

Comment: Sure there is - you just haven't yet told us what you need.

Comment: You can print any photo **full frame** on any size  paper but it will not fill the  paper edge to edge, there will be some border if the aspect ratios are different.  You will just need to trim off the part of the paper that does not have any image. Images and paper do not always have the same aspect ratio. -  https://www.shutterstock.com/blog/common-aspect-ratios-photo-image-sizes  **Print it full frame on an 8x10 or 11x16 paper and trim off any boarder and you have not changed or "compromised" your image**.

Comment: I think the answer to this has become "You take it to a print shop & tell them what you need. Answer any questions they ask."

Comment: The issue may be that the OP thinks there should be **an app** for that. It is not something that requires an App, it requires **some knowledge and the correct software/hardware**. If the OP has a computer and a printer then they do not need to go to a Print shop. If we have that info then someone should be able to supply the knowledge on how to get the file from the phone to the computer and tell the computer to print it full frame. If the OP does not have the hardware needed then "Go to a print shop" is the correct answer.

Comment: @Altima0  The ball is in your court, Provide us with info about what printing options you have, **I.E. computer/printer/software**, and we may be able to help you.

Answer (score 2):

When printing an image that has one aspect ratio on paper that has a different aspect ratio, there are two options if you don't want the image "*stretched*" in one direction. You either crop the image to match the aspect ratio of the paper, or you print the image "letterboxed" - **I.E.** With borders on one or two sides that you can trim off, making the paper match the aspect ratio of the image.

Technically, I guess, there's a third option between the two - crop a little bit less so the borders are a little smaller - but that's a compromise you need to decide on.

Most printers will default to cropping the image, but should have the ability to print the whole image if you ask them, although that may be less true with the cheaper fully-automated places.